# Declare background ignoring parents padding

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following setup:

```
<app-opener></app-opener>
<div class="main-content-wrapper">
  <app-identity></app-identity>
  <app-partners></app-partners>
</div>
```

I want to give `app-partners` a different background, but since `.main-content-wrapper` has padding, this applies to the partner section's background as well, my goal is to fill the screen.

**How do I give `app-partner`'s a background that ignores the parent's padding, without declaring padding for each child.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo element as background layer and position it relatively to the parent element:

```css
.parent {
  margin:20px;
  border:5px solid red;
  padding:20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.child {
  height:100px;
}
.child:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/17/800/800) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

With the same idea you can consider negative value for left/right or top/bottom to cover the padding:

```css
.parent {
  margin:20px;
  border:5px solid red;
  padding:20px;
}

.child {
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.child:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:-20px;
  right:-20px;
  bottom:0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/17/800/800) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this fills the whole parent. In my case there are two children, but I solely want that background for the second child.

Comment: @Tim it's about horizontal padding?

Comment: Yes, only horizontal!